# celery.chord gives IndexError: list index out of range error in celery version 3.0.19

Tags: python, runtime-error, celery

Has anyone seen this error in celery (a distribute task worker in Python) before?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcapp/.virtualenv/lister/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 228, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcapp/.virtualenv/lister/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 415, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcapp/lister/lister/tasks/__init__.py", line 69, in update_playlist_db
    video_update(videos)
  File "/home/mcapp/lister/lister/tasks/__init__.py", line 55, in video_update
    chord(tasks)(update_complete.s(update_id=update_id, update_type='db', complete=True))
  File "/home/mcapp/.virtualenv/lister/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 464, in __call__
    _chord = self.type
  File "/home/mcapp/.virtualenv/lister/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 461, in type
    return self._type or self.tasks[0].type.app.tasks['celery.chord']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This particular version of celery is 3.0.19, and happens when the celery chord feature is used.  We don't think there is any error in our application, as 99% of the time our code works correctly, but under heavier loads this error would happen.  We are trying to find out if this is an actual bug in our application or a celery bug, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

This is an error that occurs when a chord header has no tasks in it. Celery tries to access the tasks in the header using `self.tasks[0]` which results in an index error since there are no tasks in the list.